# Prometheus example alerting config does not validate

Tags: prometheus

The example config provided at: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/

```
groups:
- name: example
  rules:
  - alert: HighErrorRate
    expr: job:request_latency_seconds:mean5m{job="myjob"} > 0.5
    for: 10m
    labels:
      severity: page
    annotations:
      summary: High request latency
```

However if I try to validate this file:

```
promtool check-rules rules al.yaml 
Checking rules
  FAILED: cannot get file info

Checking al.yaml
  FAILED: parse error at line 2, char 2: unexpected <op:-> in record statement, expected "="
```

Where am I going wrong? Is this syntax outdated?

Answer (score 0):

I was using v1.8 while the document is for v2+...